# Is the following distance function (measuring the distance from a vector to a set) a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, continuity

Let $B = [a -\varepsilon, a + \varepsilon] \times [b -\varepsilon, b + \varepsilon]$ be a box in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Let $\Psi_1(w_1, w_2, \mathbf{v})$ and $\Psi_2(w_1, w_2, \mathbf{v})$ be two polynomials in $n$ variables. Let us denote $\Psi = (\Psi_1, \Psi_2)$. 
Suppose for $\mathbf{v} \in U$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$, we have that 
that $\Psi(B, \mathbf{v})$ is diffeomorphic to $B$.

What I am wodering is, is the function 
$$
H(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{v}) = d( \mathbf{y}, \partial \Psi(B, \mathbf{v}))
$$
a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times U$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Here $\partial \Psi(B, \mathbf{v})$ is the boundary of the set $\Psi(B, \mathbf{v})$, and given a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, 
$$
d(\mathbf{y}, X) = \inf_{\mathbf{x} \in X} \| \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}  \|_{\infty}.  
$$

Maybe I am just missing something simple but I am having difficulty with this. Any comments or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does your w1, w2, v, (B,v) notation mean?

Comment: Yes, for a metric d, inf{ d(a,x) : a in A } is continuous.